# c++ strncpy unexpected output

Tags: c++, string

I am reviewing the string manipulation functions, for function strncpy. I got 7 outputs instead of 3, anyone can explain? Thanks a lot.

```
    char x[] = "just see that.";
    char y[15];
    char z[10];
    char l[14];

    strcpy(y, x);

    cout << "The string in array x is: " << x
         << "\n The string in array y is: " << y << '\n';

    strncpy(z, x, 9);
    z[9] = '\n';

    cout << "The string in array z is: " << z << endl;

    strncpy(l, x, 13);
    l[13] = '\n';

    cout << "The string in array l is: " << l<< endl;
```

The output has 7 lines, like below

```
The string in array x is: just see that.
The string in array y is: just see that.
The string in array z is: just see
just see that.
The string in array l is: just see that
just see
just see that.
```

Comment: Cannot replicate: https://ideone.com/fcLWVx

Answer (score 3):

After `z[9] = '\n'` or `l[13] = '\n'` strings are not null-terminated. So printing them may lead to read out of bounds and undefined behavior.

Comment: Not entirely true. The string was not null terminated in the first place. `z[9] = '\n'` and `l[13] = '\n'` are attempts to teminate the string but based on the misunderstanding that `'\n'` is an end of string marker.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to null terminate, you should use '\0' instead of '\n'

Answer (score 2):

`strncpy` is very specific that it does NOT automatically terminate (with `NUL` == `'\0'`) the target buffer if you specify buffer size less or equal to source string length. OTOH it fills more target buffer bytes with NUL if source string is even shorter (len-2 or less). Originally, `strncpy` was designed to fill buffers for external I/O that was be used so exact number of bytes is compared without detecting NUL. It's *not* a "handy" function for "usual" string manipulation, and shall not be used for such goal.

As result, you shall *not* print a buffer filled with `strncpy` without either

1. Specifying exact maximal length (for *printf, it's e.g. "%15.15s"; I can't find direct equivalent for C++ iostreams), or
2. Explicit filling of a byte after such string with NUL, or guaranteeing that any call like strncpy(dest, src, len) will have precondition that strlen(src) <= len-1.

Currently, your program is printing some unpredicted (and possibly garbage) characters after the assigned character array, so, results are unstable, depending on platform, compiler, optimization level, etc., including chance of system crash and loss of data :(

For a safer work with C strings, I strongly recommend select some of

1. `strlcpy`, `strlcat` (OpenBSD origin).
2. `strcpy_s` and so on (C TR).
3. Any approach with array-and-length structure that is free of typical caveats (or even switch to C++ with its `string`).